# How can I rename multiple columns with numbers in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, rename, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with ~2400 columns and I would like to rename all the columns from `1` to `2400`.
My current columns names are numbers and almost all of them are duplicated.

I was trying something like that but it doesn't work :

```
# An example
import pandas as pd
# Create an example dataframe
data = {'Commander': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 'Date': ['2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08'],'Score': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])

ncol = len(df.columns)
for col in df.columns :
    for i in range(ncol) :
        df.rename(columns={col: str(i)}, inplace=True)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this `C#` code?

Comment: No, it's Python code

Comment: Your example is incomplete - it doesn't define `pd`.  You should [edit] your question to have a [mcve].  That may enable someone to reproduce your work and suggest a solution.

Comment: Am I right in saying the columns here are 'commander', 'date', and 'score'?

Comment: Yes. But this is just an example. In my real data the columns names are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can just do

```
df.columns = pd.Index(np.arange(1,len(df.columns)+1).astype(str)
```

So this just overwrites the columns with a new `Index` object generated from `np.arange` and we cast the dtype to `str` using `astype`

Example:

```
In [244]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4))
df.columns

Out[244]:
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)

In [243]:
df.columns = pd.Index(np.arange(1,len(df.columns)+1)).astype(str)
df.columns

Out[243]:
Index(['1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='object')
```

On your example:

```
In [245]:
data = {'Commander': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 'Date': ['2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08'],'Score': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df.columns = pd.Index(np.arange(1,len(df.columns)+1)).astype(str)
df.columns

Out[245]:
Index(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: pd.Index(np.arange(1,len(df.columns)+1)).astype(str)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much @EdChum

Answer (score 1):

`np.arange` certainly works, but you could also just use a `list` comprehension:

```
df.columns = [i for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

If you want them as strings, use `[str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))]`